# Why is my navbar causing my page to have extra space on the right side?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navigation

Can someone please help me figure out why there is a gap on the right side of my page?

It's driving me crazy and i've tried everything i can think of. you can see what i'm talking about [here](http://devindevelopedit.com/test).

When i disable overflow or set max-width: 100%; on the nav or body it breaks my sticky nav functionality, which i also don't understand. does anyone have any idea what's going on?

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $(".nav");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 222;
}

.navigation {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav, .nav {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
}

.nav {
  margin-top: 13px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 59px;
}

.nav.scrolled {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
}

.nav li {
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 59px;
  list-style: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navigation">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a class="smoothscroll"  href="#home" title="">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a class="smoothscroll"  href="#beats" title="">BEATS</a></li>
            <li><a class="smoothscroll"  href="#licenses" title="">LICENSES</a></li>
            <li><a class="smoothscroll"  href="#videos" title="">VIDEOS</a></li>
            <li><a class="smoothscroll"  href="#services" title="">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a class="smoothscroll"  href="#contact" title="">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Re edit: Mark a question solved by accepting an answer, not by changing the question.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for the correction, and sorry about that - just finally joined and i'm still learning the etiquette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i think it's somethings relate with

- `".row"`: i thinks you need to add '.container' to parent element like in the bootsrap 5 document about [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#example)

  ```js
  // quick way to demo
  $('.row').parent().addClass('container')
  ```
- `transform: rotate(-8deg);` in `.home-content h1`

Comment: thank you! i added containers around my rows which cut the space in half, but it's still there. when i inspect the page it looks like the navbar is extending a few pixels off the page still but i've got multiple layers around it with max-width:100%;. taking off the transform from h1 didn't make a difference either

Answer (score 0):

Your using bootstrap. According to the layout [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) your semantics are incorrect. You should follow the layout as shown below.

Notice the structure "container" > "row" > "col"

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! i fixed the bootstrap structure which cut the space in half, but now my whole page has some weird margins on both sides of the page and i'm at a total loss. do you mind checking it out again?

Comment: I'm not seeing any weird left-right margin's. I notice you had a vertical scroll before, now that's gone.